# Generically forwarding a GRPC call

Tags: grpc, grpc-java

I have a GRPC API where, following a refactor, a few packages were renamed. This includes the `package` declaration in one of our proto files that defines the API. Something like this:

```
package foo;

service BazApi {
    rpc FooEventStream(stream Ack) returns (stream FooEvent);
}
```

which was changed to

```
package bar;

service BazApi {
    rpc FooEventStream(stream Ack) returns (stream FooEvent);
}
```

The server side is implemented using `grpc-java` with scala and monix on top.

This all works fine for clients that use the new proto files, but for old clients that were built on top of the old proto files, this causes problems: `UNIMPLEMENTED: Method not found: foo.BazApi/FooEventStream`.

The actual data format of the messages passed over the GRPC API has not changed, only the package.

Since we need to keep backwards compatibility, I've been looking into a way to make the old clients work while keeping the name change.

I was hoping to make this work with a generic `ServerInterceptor` which would be able to inspect an incoming call, see that it's from an old client (we have the client version in the headers) and redirect/forward it to the renamed service. (Since it's just the package name that changed, this is easy to figure out e.g. `foo.BazApi/FooEventStream` -> `bar.BazApi/FooEventStream`)

However, there doesn't seem to be an elegant way to do this. I think it's possible by starting a new `ClientCall` to the correct endpoint, and then handling the `ServerCall` within the interceptor by delegating to the `ClientCall`, but that will require a bunch of plumbing code to properly handle unary/clientStreaming/serverStreaming/bidiStreaming calls.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can easily change the server, you can have it support both names simultaneously. You can consider a solution where you register your service twice, with two different descriptors.

Every service has a [`bindService()`](https://grpc.github.io/grpc-java/javadoc/io/grpc/BindableService.html#bindService--) method that returns a `ServerServiceDefinition`. You can pass the definition to the server via the normal `serverBuilder.addService()`.

So you could get the normal `ServerServiceDefinition` and then rewrite it to the new name and then register the new name.

```java
BazApiImpl service = new BazApiImpl();
serverBuilder.addService(service); // register "bar"

ServerServiceDefinition barDef = service.bindService();
ServerServiceDefinition fooDefBuilder = ServerServiceDefinition.builder("foo.BazApi");
for (ServerMethodDefinition<?,?> barMethodDef : barDef.getMethods()) {
  MethodDescriptor desc = barMethodDef.getMethodDescriptor();
  String newName = desc.getFullMethodName().replace("foo.BazApi/", "bar.BazApi/");
  desc = desc.toBuilder().setFullMethodName(newName).build();
  foDefBuilder.addMethod(desc, barMethodDef.getServerCallHandler());
}
serverBuilder.addService(fooDefBuilder.build()); // register "foo"
```

Comment: Nice solution!  earlier this year I could have used it when I discovered inadvertently that even though protobufs never send the package name over the wire a grpc service _does_!  I still don't get why, since, for the use cases I imagine, the tuple "listening port, service" should be sufficient; I don't get why you'd need to distinguish services by the triple "listening port, package, service" instead.

Comment: This works like a charm. Thanks for putting the time in to explain this!

Answer (score 3):

Using the lower-level "channel" API you can make a proxy without *too* much work. You mainly just proxy events from a `ServerCall.Listener` to a `ClientCall` and the `ClientCall.Listener` to a `ServerCall`. You get to learn about the lower-level `MethodDescriptor` and the rarely-used `HandlerRegistry`. There's also some complexity to handle flow control (`isReady()` and `request()`).

I made an example a while back, but never spent the time to merge it to grpc-java itself. It is currently available [on my random branch](https://github.com/ejona86/grpc-java/blob/grpc-proxy/examples/src/main/java/io/grpc/examples/grpcproxy/GrpcProxy.java). You should be able to get it working just by changing `localhost:8980` and by re-writing the `MethodDescriptor` passed to `channel.newCall(...)`. Something akin to:

```java
MethodDescriptor desc = serverCall.getMethodDescriptor();
if (desc.getFullMethodName().startsWith("foo.BazApi/")) {
  String newName = desc.getFullMethodName().replace("foo.BazApi/", "bar.BazApi/");
  desc = desc.toBuilder().setFullMethodName(newName).build();
}
ClientCall<ReqT, RespT> clientCall
    = channel.newCall(desc, CallOptions.DEFAULT);
```

Comment: Oh, I realize now this is a bit more than you likely need. I've provided another answer that doesn't do a full proxy.